# Getting the Short/Long Name of the Translate value

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I have a Field naming SUBJECT with translate value:

Translate Value: Math

Long Name: Mathematics

Short Name: Mathematics

Now I have a Record naming PS_CLASS which has SUBJECT as field, now basically the values of SUBJECT in PS_CLASS would be 'Math'.

The problem is I want it to store the Long Name of that translate value, so instead of SUBJECT having 'Math' as value, it will have the value of 'Mathematics'.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Field' = 'Column'? Some sample data would really help here.

Comment: give script of your tables and what u try ?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson for example I have a record PS_CLASS, then one of that record field is SUBJECT.

Since SUBJECT field has a translate value of Math and Long Name of that SUBJECT is MATHEMATICS. Since the value that would show in PS_CLASS would be MATH, but I want it to be Mathematics which is the long name.

Comment: Any chance of a working demo? I'm still not sure what 'records' and 'fields' are. Does this depend on Peoplesoft? I know SQL and PL/SQL but I don't know anything about Peoplesoft.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, yes unfortunately it does depend on peoplesoft. sorry

Comment: Why do you want to store the translate value? The idea is to store a 4 char value in your real table, but for display purposes you'd fetch the short/long translate. This means your PS_CLASS does not need larger fields. The XLAT table will have a larger field, but will only have to store it once.

Comment: @PeterPaff: This is because of what is requested, i dont even know if this is possible.

Comment: @Link it's certainly possible, but you are going to have to change every page that uses that record field. I don't understand why anyone would request this though? Why would anyone ask you to save a value in a more inefficient way?